# Does every non-contradictory formal system have a model in ZF?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Is the following statement true?

- Every non-contradictory formal system has a model in ZF.

This seems true, because non-contradictness and existence of model seems equivalent. But how to prove this?

Comment: What is a formal system in this context?

Comment: @AsafKaragila A formal system is functional symbols, relational symbols, logical connectives, 0, 1, universal and existence quantifiers, modus ponens, a finite set of axioms. I hope, nothing changes if we add here also set comprehension operator, to make ZF itself a formal system.

Comment: ZF is not finitely axiomatisable in first order logic, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ugh, writing my (considered by myself a breakthrough) logic article I forgot this (that ZF is not finitely axiomatisable in first order logic). This complicates things. If ZF isn't an instance of first order logic + a finite set of axioms, then how to "classify" ZF? ZF is an instance of first order logic + a (countable) set of axioms. What else could it be classified as?

Comment: Probably you need the set of axioms to be recursive, not merely countable.

Comment: @GEdgar ZF proves that every countable consistent theory has a model. If you want a *recursive* model, i.e., a model with domain $\mathbb{N}$ such that the interpretations of the symbols in the language are recursive functions and relations, then you need the set of axioms to be recursive.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on how you define “formal system.” If you mean some first-order theory over a countable language, then the answer is yes; ZF proves that all such consistent theories have a model.

If you mean an arbitrary first-order theory, you are essentially asking whether the completeness theorem can be proved in ZF. Assuming ZF is consistent, this is not possible. There are many statements equivalent over ZF to this one across many areas of math, including the ultrafilter lemma, the theorem that all nonzero rings have a prime ideal, and Tychonoff’s theorem for compact Hausdorff spaces. These statements are weaker than the full axiom of choice.

Comment: "ZF proves that all such consistent theories have a model." I asked not whether model existence can be proved, but whether we can construct a particular set which is a model of such a consistent theory.

Comment: In your definition of first-order theory over a countable language, do you assume that the set of axioms of the theory is finite?

Comment: @porton No, of course not. Are you familiar with the completeness theorem?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Sorry, for me blunting. I've realized: ZF cannot model itself, because otherwise it would prove its own consistency.

Comment: No, me is not quite blunting. It seems that ZF can indeed model itself (consider a countable model of ZF), but can't prove that the model is a model of a consistent system. What is a model of a contradictory system?

Comment: In a Godel's theorem, PA models itself, it is just unable to prove "consistency" of the model. (What is consistency of a model?)

Comment: @porton I am not sure what you mean by "construct a particular set which is a model". If you mean "Can we constructively prove that for all countable consistent theories $T$, $T$ has a model?", then you should be asking about some specific constructive system such as IZF or CZF and not about ZF (and the answer will be "no"). I did not assume the set of axioms over the theory is finite - many interesting theories like ZF and PA are not finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: @MarkSaving Like constructing PA in PA by Godel. He constructs such one, but can't prove that it is consistent. Unlike Godel, I want to construct a *model* not just the formal system itself.